# System.Net.WebException: The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized

Tags: error, .net

I used below code to access sharepoint defualt webservices, in console application and it is working fine, but when i used dll from same console application into .net webapplication it thrown an error for authentication error.

i.e. i am not able to access webservice in webapplication:-

```
var wsWebs = new SPWebWebService.Webs()
                                 {
                                     Url = String.Format("{0}/{1}",
                                                         parentSiteUrl,
                                                         Constants.WebServices.SharePoint.Webs),
                                     Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
                                 };

                var webCollectionNode = wsWebs.GetWebCollection();
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is the credentials you are logged in as in the command window context have access to SharePoint, and are being appropriately passed using `CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials`. These creds are different in the web app context. Try creating a hardcoded set of creds and see if that changes anything:

```
System.Net.NetworkCredential myCred = new NetworkCredential(
"yourusername","your password","your domain");
```

Disclaimer: I haven't tried this, this is just my theory. Hopefully it'll get you going in the right direction.